# using integrals, how do I find the average distance between an origin and points on a circle $(x-2)^2+y^2=4$

Tags: calculus, integration

The advice given is to use $ \int \sqrt{1-\cos x}$  twice, once from $ 0 $ to $\pi$ and then $\pi$ to $ 2\pi$.

I don't completely understand how this is relevant to finding the average distance.

Comment: points on the circle or the points on the disk? The advice you have been given works for the points in the disk.

Comment: oh could you explain how the cos advice helps? thanks so much for the responses. i have two problems. points on the circle and points in the circle. the advice should work for one of those. but i used the equation you had posted previously for points IN the circle, is that incorrect? also i multiplied the double integral by 1/(area of the circle) , thats how do you average i think right?

Comment: let me get a paper and pen. I also learned the subject lately.

Comment: sure, oh ok cool thanks

Comment: is the answer $8/\pi$?

Comment: that seems right or at least close i dont have the answer yet, is that for point on the circle or in the circle?

Comment: ON the circle now :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\theta$ be the angle between the positive x-axis and the line joining a sample point $(x,y)$ and the origin. Then the distance $d$ between this sample point and the origin is $4\cos\theta$. So the problem is reduced to finding the average value of the function $d(\theta)=4\cos\theta$ on the interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$(Draw the plot to see why the interval is chosen so).

$$\overline{d}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}4\cos\theta\mbox{d}\theta=\frac{8}{\pi}.$$

Comment: great thanks for the help!!